# Strange behavior of batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two cmd files.
child.cmd:

```
@echo off
exit 1
```

parent.cmd:

```
@echo off
cmd /C child.cmd
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
   echo OK
) else (
   echo ERROR
)
```

If to run parent.cmd, then ERROR will be printed.

But if a little change parent.cmd, then OK will be printed:

```
@echo off
if "YES" EQU "YES" (
   cmd /C child.cmd
   if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
      echo OK
   ) else (
      echo ERROR
   )
)
```

Why OK is printed in the second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside a code block you need `delayed expansion` to access `%variables%`:

```
 @echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this syntax without delayed expansion:

```
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 ( echo error )
```